# 'table_priv' broken when trying to grant privileges to other users in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So, I have this mock database (for a uni assignment) for an IKEA shop. Here, i have created a bunch of views from different columns and made a bunch of new users without any apparent issues.

```
-- Active: 1695563150024@@127.0.0.1@3306@ikea
USE ikea;

--No 1
CREATE VIEW view_service_and_total AS
SELECT o.OrderID AS `Order ID`, DATE_FORMAT(o.OrderDate, '%d %M %y') AS `Date`, 
s.ServiceDesc AS `Service Type`, s.Price AS `Service`, SUM(s.Price) + SUM(od.Price * od.Qty) AS `Total`
FROM orders AS o 
LEFT JOIN orderdetails AS od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
LEFT JOIN servicedetails AS sd ON o.OrderID = sd.OrderID
LEFT JOIN services AS s ON s.`ServiceID` = sd.`ServiceID`
WHERE ISNULL(s.ServiceDesc) = 0 AND ISNULL(s.Price) = 0
GROUP BY `Order ID`;


--No 3
CREATE VIEW nama_employees_sales AS
SELECT e.EmployeeID, 
CONCAT(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) AS `Employee Name`,
j.JobDesc AS `Job`, j.Salary
FROM employees AS e 
LEFT JOIN jobs AS j ON e.JobID = j.JobID
ORDER BY `Employee Name` ASC;


--No 4
CREATE VIEW food_sales AS
SELECT r.F_OrderID AS ID, DATE_FORMAT(r.F_OrderDate, '%d %M %y') AS DATE,
CONCAT(e.`FirstName`, ' ', e.`LastName`) AS `Employee Name`, p.ProductName AS `Order Food`,
fod.Price, fod.`Qty`, (fod.Price * fod.`Qty`) AS `Total`
FROM restaurant AS r
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON r.`EmployeeID` = e.`EmployeeID`
LEFT JOIN forderdetails AS fod ON fod.`F_OrderID` = r.`F_OrderID`
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON p.`ArticleID` = fod.`ArticleID`;


SELECT * FROM food_sales;
--No 5

CREATE USER 'Aldwin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'aldsetiawan';
CREATE USER 'Hansen'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'hnsedrick';
CREATE USER 'Reza'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'rzsatyawijaya';
CREATE USER 'Sintya'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'styoktaviani';
```

However, the problem comes when I tried to grant privileges to any users

```
--No 6
GRANT SELECT ON food_sales 
TO 'Aldwin'@'localhost';
```

Here the error says that

```
"Table 'tables_priv' is marked as crashed and should be repaired".
```

I tried running

```
REPAIR TABLE tables_priv;
```

but since its not an actual table in the database, the method doesnt work.
How exactly do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tables_priv` is in the mysql database - `repair table mysql.tables_priv`